# Framed \newenvironment without new packages

Tags: packages, environments, boxes, framed

Is there a solution to make a frame around an environment without using any new packages? (with boxes or something)

Comment: The basic `\fbox` does that: presumably you want something more complex?

Comment: Any why the clause **no new packages** when your life gets 100% easier using things like `tcolorbox` or `mdframed`?

Comment: "The basic \fbox does that: presumably you want something more complex? – Joseph Wright" - I want add a frame in \newenvironment options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just the LaTeX kernel for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\mybox
\newenvironment{framedbox}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}}
  {%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \fbox{\usebox{\mybox}}%
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{framedbox}
  Hello world
\end{framedbox}

\end{document}
```

though I'm not clear on what the content to be boxed up actually is.